# PHP abstract class constructor not working

Tags: php, oop, constructor, abstract-class, abstract

I wish to access some of my variables in a way like this:

```
System->Config->URL
```

Which in this case 'System' is my core class, 'Config' is an array and 'URL' is an item inside the array. Here is my 'system.php' code:

```
<?php

abstract class System {

    public $Config;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->Config = (object) array('URL' => 'localhost');
    }
}

echo System->Config->URL;

?>
```

When I run the above code I just see this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ';'
```

Which is pointing out my `echo` line.

Now if I eliminate the abstract idea, and use this one, that works very well!

```
<?php

class System {

    public $Config;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->Config = (object) array('URL' => 'localhost');
    }
}

$System = new System();
echo $System->Config->URL;

?>
```

I've also tried to mix up the `static` and `abstract` keywords, but that didn't worked also. I even gave up with the `__construct` function and made a very normal method named 'Ready', but still couldn't call that when the class is defined `abstract`.

Does anyone knows what's wrong here? I have seen the similar codes works very well.

Any help or idea would highly appreciated!

Comment: You class is abstract and not initiated in first example.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I thought that it doesn't need to initialize! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. The second example works because it is right. An abstract class is a class you need to extend, and then you can instantiate that (child) class just as in your working example.

You might need to read up on what "abstract" does.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the definition of an "abstract" class. It's a class that cannot be instantiated. Only the classes that inherit it can be instantiated.

Comment: You must be thinking of a static class ;)

Comment: I just look at an example of someone else to see how he did that, and then I lose the point, I guess. I had a bug on the other part, then, everything came together and that's happened! :D ... Thanks again!